# Magento: Need an if case for is a product name/sku/id is equal to X

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Going to try to type this is the easiest way I can.

What I am looking to do is filter options I'm coding by hand (long story) by creating a large if statement of if elses.

IE: If the product sku=1234 then show the following. I'd only have about 14 products so this isn't as insane a thought as I had thought. But I can't seem to figure out the code I would need.

Please let me know if you'd need me to provide more details and any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: provide something you have tried..

Answer (score 0):

`if($product->getSku() == 12345)`

What are you talking about!? :-)

You want to filter the products?

Build a observer, listen to the product_collection_load_before event, check the params sent to the action and then change the product_colletion where.